# MVC3 how to update URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url

When a visitor navigate to my MVC3 site, the site generate values and stores them in the Session variables. If the visitor click on the Brand Logo on the site, it will redirect back to the home landing page of my site. I want the URL to have information stored in session been shown as parameters in the URL. Here is an example....

1. User navigate to my site:

   `www.mysite.com`: `mysite` generates some values and I store it in `Session`
2. User selects a home link in my site in the site logo, I want the URL to look like this in the browser:

   ```
   www.mysite.com?param0=0&paramN=N
   ```

Is this possible? I have read some documentation on URL rewrite but none of the solutions I have seen so far seems obvious for what I need to do. Thanks

Comment: Not possible in MVC3. http://forums.asp.net/p/1747459/4722341.aspx/1?Re+how+to+update+URL+